# what is the syntax for sending a socket GET request with user input

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.x, http-status-code-400

I am trying to prompt user for URL so it can read any page, but I keep getting the 400 bad request error when I run my program.

I have established a socket connection with the host from my input. But when I try sending a GET request, it blows up on me, with a 400 bad request error. What can I do please?

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    url = raw_input('Enter - ')
    splt = url.split('/')
    mysock.connect((splt[2], 80))
    mysock.send('GET url \n\n')
except:
    print 'invalid URL'

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1 ):
        break
    print data
mysock.close()
```

Comment: You might want to use [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead.

Comment: You *definitely* want to use `requests` instead.

Comment: please can you help me solve this problem using the urllib2.
 prompt the user for the
URL so it can read any web page. You can use split(’/’) to break the URL into
its component parts so you can extract the host name for the socket connect call.
Add error checking using try and except to handle the condition where the user
enters an improperly formatted or non-existent URL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you aren't calling the GET properly.  When you write

> mysock.send('GET url \n\n')

You aren't embedding the variable "url" into the command but simply a string with the phrase "url".

I don't know, but that could be worth checking.

My own code looks like this:

> cmd = 'GET '+address+' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
>   cmd = cmd.encode()
>   mysock.send(cmd)

Where "address" is the name of the address entered by the user.